# Why can't javac access List, given that List is part of the JRL

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to compile a Spring Boot tutorial, but am getting an error.

```
[ERROR] /Users/jimstockwell/Birds/application/src/main/java/com/okta/developer/BirdController.java:[23,35] cannot access List
  class file for List not found
```

I'm using Maven, and a very sparse pom file. (I've tried javac directly too.)

I'll post more information as question develop in the comments, since posting the whole project seems excessive.   :)

The apparently offending code is:

```
package com.okta.developer;

import com.okta.developer.animals.bird.Bird;
import com.okta.developer.animals.bird.BirdPersistence;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class BirdController {

    private BirdPersistence birdPersistence;

    public BirdController(BirdPersistence birdPersistence) {
        this.birdPersistence = birdPersistence;
    }

    @GetMapping("bird")
    public List<Bird> getBird() {
        return birdPersistence.get();
    }

    @PostMapping("bird")
    public void saveBird(@RequestBody Bird bird) {
        birdPersistence.save(bird);
    }
}
```

(and line 23 is the one that reads: return birdPersistence.get();)

I don't understand what's going on. Since List is part of lang.util, how can the compiler say "cannot access List"?

Can anyone give some insight?  Thanks in advance.

Edit:
If I change getBird as follows (and add ArrayList to imports),
it compiles fine:

```
    public List<Bird> getBird() {
        return new ArrayList<Bird>();
/*        return birdPersistence.get(); */
    }
```

Comment: Can you compile...anything? A basic Hello World? Can you access other classes in `java.util` package?

Comment: Thank you, yes to both.  If I comment out the GetMapping annotation and following method, all compiles well.  I can say "List x = new java.util.ArrayList();" in saveBird with no compilation problem.

Comment: What does `birdPersistence.get();` return?

Comment: @Kayaman, great question.  It returns List<Bird>.  AND.  If I change it to return ArrayList<Bird> instead (and update imports, and actually give it an ArrayList<Bird> to return), then it compiles fine.

Comment: Uh... I put it back the way it was, and it compiles fine now.  That's embarrassing as I must have changed *something*.  Well, @Kayaman, thank you for investing your brainpower into this.

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't invest *that* much into it. Weird error though.